# CakePHP 1.3 - Jquery - Get data in a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, cakephp

Technologies used: CakePHP 1.3, Jquery

Given a first array, I want to set the values of a second array depending of the value selected in this first array.

Concretly, first array is a list of companies, second array must be filled with the job offers of the company selected. For this, on change I do an ajax request to get from the database the job offers.

What is not working is that it seems I cannot provide my Javascript with a valid JSON.
The JSON that is sent back always begin with a new line. (One time I think I saw it on Firefox like a "\n", Chrome only put a new line).

I managed to used this javascript in another context (Spring MVC), and it was working. So my main suspect is my CakePHP controller.

I already tried many things, like manipulating the data as a string in the JS, but none worked, so I must ask myself.
Do any of you already stumbled upon this problem?

Here the codes:

Html:

```
<div class="form" style="width: auto">

        <?php
        echo $form->create('Slot', array('url' => array('controller' => 'slot', 'action' => 'add')));
        echo $form->input('company_id', array('label' => 'Company:', 'options' => $companies)) . "<br/>";
        echo $form->input('offer_id', array('label' => 'Offer', 'options' => array('0' => 'Chose a company first!'))) . '<br/>';
        echo $form->end('Register') . '<br/>';
        ?>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/admin/slots/getCompanyOffers/" + this.value,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        var select = $('#SlotOfferId');
        select.empty();
        select.append($('<option/>'));

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            select.append($('<option/>').text(value).attr('value', key));
        });
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
function admin_getCompanyOffers($companyId) {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if (!$this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
        echo "POST mandatory";
        return;
    }

    $offers = $this->Offer->find('all', array('recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => array('id', 'title'),
        'conditions' => array('company_id' => $companyId)));

    echo json_encode(Set::extract('/Offer/.', $offers));
}
```

Comment: I think that you should set proper header before response. Simplest way: `header('Content-Type: application/json')`

Comment: @Bart This line must added in the controller's method?

Comment: Yes, e.g. just before `echo json_encode...` line

Comment: I just tried, but nothing changed.
Still getting a new line at the begining of my JSON, and the `$.ajax` do not recognize it as valid JSON it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
function admin_getCompanyOffers($companyId) {
    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if (!$this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
        echo "POST mandatory";
        return;
    }

    $offers = $this->Offer->find('all', array('recursive' => -1,
        'fields' => array('id', 'title'),
        'conditions' => array('company_id' => $companyId)));

   return json_encode(Set::extract('/Offer/.', $offers));


}
```

Comment: I changed the `echo` to `return` as you said, but it didn't work.
Still getting a new line at the begining of the JSON, and `$.ajax` isn't recognizing it as valid JSON.